# ios in-app purchase prompt not displaying

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am using [Glassfy](https://glassfy.io) in my Ionic Vue app so a user can purchase a product or subscription. I am able to get the products from my Apple Store Connect account and display them in the App through Glassfy.

However when I try to run the purchase function, nothing happens. I don't get any error code or anything.

This is my code:

```
    const sub = ref();

    onMounted(async () => {
      initGlassfy();
    });

    const initGlassfy = async () => {
      try {
        await Glassfy.initialize({
          apiKey: "4ba35c9a634d44158ee6713cfffd83ce",
          watcherMode: false,
        });

        getSku();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    const getSku = async () => {
      try {
        subOne.value = await Glassfy.skuWithId({ identifier: "30Days" });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };

    const purchase = async () => {
      try {
        await Glassfy.purchaseSku({ sku: sub.value });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
```

I am running the app on my iPhone through Xcode. I have also tried deploying it and opening it through Testflight, but with the same result.
I have already added In-app Purchase as a capability in Xcode.

Does anyone know what I am during wrong?

Comment: You seem to have two refs: `sub` and `subOne`. Maybe it's just this?

Answer (score 1):

+1

Got the same problem. Neither "transaction" nor the error will be logged in this example.

Tried it with a sandbox tester on my local physical device.

```
try {
  console.log("going to purchase");
  const transaction = await Glassfy.purchaseSku({ sku });
  console.log("transaction", transaction);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```